# How to use import * as styles in creat-react-app with css modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I found that I can not make to work named import with css modules in create-reat-app.

The following code fires an error:

`import * as styles from './PriceTable.module.css';`

and the error is:

`export 'table' (imported as 'styles') was not found in './PriceTable.module.css' (possible exports: default)`

I know that I can just use `import styles from './PriceTable.module.css';` but this is not what I need as I am using parcel and it requires named imports for tree shaking.

I would appreciate it if anyone has any thoughts about this how to fix it?

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as styles from './PriceTable.module.css';


const PriceTable = (props) => {    
    console.log(styles)
    return (
        <div className={styles.table}>This is a price table {props.widget} and the hex color is: {props.color} !</div>
    )
}

export default PriceTable;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-widgets",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "serve-build": "serve -s build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:widget": "parcel build src/index.js --no-source-maps --dist-dir docs"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-noyce-9btg7?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @whygee thank you for looking into this. Yes, it works in CodeSandbox but doing absolutely the same thing in local fires an error. Tried to replicate that with the same package.json and structure. Drives me crazy :(

Comment: can you share your `package.json` please

Comment: I'm kinda confused because you said you are using Parcel but from your `package.json` it doesn't look like it

Comment: @whygee yes, sorry, updated, another one was just a test without parcel just to understand if with clean package.json it would work but no, the same error.

Comment: Try downdraging `react-scripts` to v4, it worked for me

Comment: v4 has too many vulnerabilities, really hope to find a fix for 5.0.0

Comment: Your best bet would be to post an issue on react github and/or Parcel github